# wrong order in SQL using PDO

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have this query, which will be stored in a variable named `$query` (the actual query is much more complex, but this example successfully addresses my problem):

```
select * from
(
    select
        id_field as 'id', 
        date_field as 'date', 
        name_field as 'name', 
        cast((@counter := @counter + 1) AS SIGNED) as 'counter'
    from my_table
    cross join (select @counter := 0) as tmp
) as x
```

At some point, the final query will be:

```
$final_sql = "select * from ($query) t order by date desc"; //this can't be changed
```

What's happening is that I'm not getting the rows ordered by date, instead I'm getting some random order.

I've narrowed the problem to the double `select * from` while running the query with php/pdo on the server (localhost works fine). If I run the raw sql directly in database (localhost or server) it also works fine

If `$query` was like this, then I get the correct order (`select * from` removed):

```
    select
        id_field as 'id', 
        date_field as 'date', 
        name_field as 'name', 
        cast((@counter := @counter + 1) AS SIGNED) as 'counter'
    from my_table
    cross join (select @counter := 0) as tmp
```

But I've also noticed that if I keep the double `select * from` and get rid of the variables, then it will work as expected (but I need that column so it's not an option)

```
select * from
(
    select
        id_field as 'id', 
        date_field as 'date', 
        name_field as 'name'
    from my_table
) as x
```

So, what is going on here?! How can I make it work on my server, just like my localhost?

```
localhost:
db > MySQL 8.0.25
php > 7.3.27
pdo > mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407

server:
db > MariaDB 10.1.44
php > 7.3.17
pdo > mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407
```

Comment: There's no problem here. SQL (MySQL or any other flavour) doesn't guarantee an order unless you ask it to. Add an ORDER BY clause to your query.

Comment: as last ditch effort, you can always store the query result  in array and use php's ```usort``` function

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular but and order is set in $final_sql and it works everywhere except webpage on server

Comment: @Matias Perhaps, then, you could post the table design, preferably as a `CREATE TABLE...`, and some sample data that demonstrates the problem. If the problem is not in the query then the data is the next place to look.

Comment: You really should use exactly the same stack on both dev and prod servers! Mariadb is **not** mysql, you will bump into lot more problems down the line!

Comment: @Shadow You are right and I'm planning to, but up to this point I'm using fair basic and simple querys. This is the only one kind of unusual

Comment: There is no guaranteed order unless you add an order by. So, what is your question again?

Answer (score 0):

By nature the resultset of  subquery are unsorted, while mysql keeps it mariadb skips it

What you can do is making a LIMIT with an ORDER BY so that mysql and mariadb keops the order you need

```
select * from
(
    select
        id_field as 'id', 
        date_field as 'date', 
        name_field as 'name', 
        cast((@counter := @counter + 1) AS SIGNED) as 'counter'
    from my_table
    cross join (select @counter := 0) as tmp
    ORDER BY date_field 
    LIMIT 18446744073709551615
) as x
```